# JWT access token vs refresh token (creating)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I am creating a Asp.net Core REST service. Currently doing authentication via JWT bearer tokens.

Right now, my code looks like:

```
        DateTimeOffset dtNow = DateTime.Now;

        Claim[] claims = new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, strUsername),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, dtNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)
        };

        JwtSecurityToken jwtAccess = new JwtSecurityToken(_options.Issuer, _options.Audience, claims, dtNow.DateTime, dtNow.DateTime.Add(_options.AccessTokenExpiration),
                                                          _options.SigningCredentials);

        var response = new
        {
            access_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtAccess),
            token_type = "Bearer",
            expires_in = (int)_options.AccessTokenExpiration.TotalSeconds,
            refresh_token = ""
        };
```

Questions:

1. Right now, my access tokens are good for 1hr and my refresh
   tokens for 60 days. Are these reasonable values?
2. Not seeing much
   documentation on how to create the refresh_token... is this created
   *exactly* like the access token, but just with the different timeout?
3. Its my understanding that I'm supposed to store the refresh token in a database and if the user sends a refresh token request, I need to verify the signature of the token AND make sure its in my database?
4. When the user requests a refresh token, I'm supposed to return the same refresh_token whether its expired or not and let the user worry about getting a new one?
5. A user should only have one refresh token at a time, correct? If they do another password_grant, I just overwrite the refresh token as if they are getting a brand new one?
6. Final question is, I see people are doing JWT authentication which is why I'm doing it lol, but how is this any different then just sending a username / password over HTTPS? I understand that the JTW carries the state/roles/etc in the payload, so that saves a DB call, but since authentication tokens are short lived, they'd have to get a new token every 5 minutes, so this all seems kind of like a wash, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. This is all dependent on the needs of your application but these do sound like reasonable numbers.
2. They are not created the same. An access token is typically a token that contains the JWT. A refresh token is a reference token that must be saved on the provider and the looked back up when it is passed in for a new access token.
3. Refresh tokens do not have a signature to verify. Basically you will pass over the information like client Id and secret plus the refresh token and this will allow you to get a new access token. Like a username and password being saved for a long period of time that can be blacklisted if necessary.
4. No you can update the refresh token every time they request a new access token this will give you a "sliding" refresh token.
5. They can have different tokens for each app but per application it is fine to overwrite their previous refresh token when they do a new login.
6. Yes the users will have to get a new access token ever ~30 minutes but this also helps when your role provider is not the same as your application. This gives an API a way to look at roles without having to call the authorization server. The number of requests saves is drastic   when you house the information in the token and only have to re-get that information every 30 minutes instead of an extra HTTP request to a separate server for every API call or post back.

Hopefully some of this was helpful. I am speaking for minor experience but there are very good resources explaining this stuff from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) or basically anything from the guys on IdentityServer3 (and now 4)

Comment: Thanks Tim. Some clarification please. #2... the code I posted, would I create refresh_token, the same as I created jwtAccess except for 1) the 60 day expiration 2) save it in the DB? You confused me with your #2 answer since every response object I've seen, the access_token and refresh_token look kinda similar?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Sorry for the confusion. There are two types of tokens a self-containing token and a reference token. 

In a self-containing token all the information, like claims and roles, will be stored in the token and can be retrieved without calling the authorization service. This would be your access token.

A reference token is just an identifier that is stored in the database. The identifier links to all the information you need but you must call the authorization service to get the information. This would be your reference token.

Comment: 2) and 3) are not correct. Since the refresh token format is completely implementation-specific (exactly like an access token or an authorization code), one could use JWT, SAML or a custom format.

Comment: If you were to use a JWT or Saml you would be defeating the purpose. A JWT houses information that the refresh token should not know/care about. It SHOULD only be an ID that is stored on the authorization provider.

Comment: Really, no, that's not what the specification says: "A refresh token is a string representing the authorization granted to the client by the resource owner.  The string is usually opaque to the client.", which is exactly the same definition as the one used for access tokens: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.4. One is totally free to decide how to format a refresh token. It doesn't have to be a "reference string".

Comment: @Pinpoint "The token denotes an identifier used to retrieve the authorization information." You are correct you can implement however you want but it only is an identifier, not anything else.

Comment: A refresh token can be self-contained and have all the authorization data stored inside it without having to rely on a database (which is even quite frequent for implementations that require maximal performance: in this case, the token contains all the claims it needs to avoid a DB lookup and revocation can be implemented using an in-memory blacklist). Don't mix up what the specification says and what popular implementations like IdSrv do.

Comment: @Pinpoint While that is not explicitly prohibited it would be very problematic. If the refresh token has all the information that a user needs to stay logged in without having to call the authorization server there would be no way to revoke the refresh token and would be effectively the same as just giving a long live access token.

Comment: `If the refresh token has all the information that a user needs to stay logged in without having to call the authorization server` > heh, I never said that. The fact a token is self-contained doesn't mean it is readable by the entire world (specially if it's encrypted and signed). And it doesn't mean that a client will be able to use it to gain unlimited access or to generate valid tokens without relying on the authorization server for that (that would be a major security issue).

Comment: True. As long as the authorization server is the only thing that can get the information then I guess it doesn't matter what you store. Valid point.